# Preventing table overflow in quarto

Tags: quarto

Good day

I have created a quarto document in r studio and I'm rendering it to pdf using the YAML below

```
title: "My report"
author: "Author name here"
date: '26 September 2023'
format:
  pdf:
    toc: true
    number-sections: true
    colorlinks: true
    lof: true
    lot: true
    papersize: 'a4'
editor: visual
```

I then create a gt table using the code below and I often find that my tables start on one page and end on another (based on the amount of text above etc).

```
{r}
#| tbl-cap: Average load factor and visitor arrivals by year
#| label: tbl-monthly
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
summary_table_lf <- load_factor %>%
   group_by(year(Date)) %>% 
   summarise_all(mean) %>% 
   rename(`Avg Load (000)`= load_factor_nominal,
         `Avg Load (%)`= load_fact_percent,
         `Avg Visitors`= visitors,
         `Avg Locals`= locals,
         `Google Search`=google_search) %>% 
   select(-Date) %>% 
   gt() %>% 
      fmt_number(columns = 2:6, decimals = 0) %>% 
      fmt_percent(columns = 3, decimals = 1) %>% 
      cols_align(align = 'center', columns=everything()) %>% 
        tab_header(
           title = md("**Country Average Load Factor and Visitor Data**"),
           subtitle = md("*monthly*"  )) %>% 
             tab_source_note(source_note = 'Source: Enter name here[![enter image description here][1]][1]') %>% 
             tab_footnote(footnote = 'Not a full year end August 2023',
                   locations = cells_body(column=1, rows = 10)) %>% 
             tab_style(style = list(cell_text(weight = "bold")),
                   locations=cells_column_labels(everything())) %>% 
             opt_table_lines(extent = 'default') %>% 
             tab_options(
                   column_labels.border.bottom.width = px(3),
                   column_labels.border.top.width = px(3),
                   column_labels.border.bottom.color = 'black',
                   column_labels.border.top.color='black',
                   footnotes.border.bottom.color = 'black',
                   row_group.border.bottom.color  = 'black'
          )

  summary_table_lf
```

I have tried `out.width='70%'` and other approaches but not of them work. What setting either in the code chunk or YAML can I use to ensure that a table renders on a new page if the existing page is too small to be fully displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A manual fix would be to add `\clearpage` by hand, e.g.

````
---
title: "Section Numbering Test"
format:
  pdf:
    number-sections: true
    papersize: 'a4'
---


## Table strechtes across two pages


```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
gt::gt(mtcars, mtcars)
```


## Table on next page


\clearpage


```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
gt::gt(mtcars, mtcars)
```
````